# Any way to make VS 2015 remember runsettings file?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, runsettings

We use a .runsettings file to enforce 64 bit execution environment (and appropriate code coverage) for unit tests in visual studio 2015. While more than half of the time VS will remember the selected file when opening a solution, it does sometimes forget and we have to re-select the file.

Is there any way to make this selection more permanent for the solution, so that it is loaded every time the solution is opened?

Comment: Reported several times at connect.microsoft.com.  Pretty vague since everybody posts "doesn't work" like you did, but seems like known problem with status deferred.  Some hint that Update 2 might fix it, currently in RC.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, i did search for "runsettings" and "testsettings" over on connect and it has no results. Can you link one of them here?

Comment: nvm, I logged one for meself - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2460518

Comment: @StingyJack: I piggy-backed on yours on connect, I can reliably repro the issue every time. Not enough space here to explain the repro (see your issue at connect for the details), but in short: the only Workaround is to keep the Test Explorer open and visible when closing or opening the Solution. Auto-hiding it or making it a tab behind another tab will not work.

Comment: @HansPassant - despite all those reports it still didnt get transferred from connect to devcomm until someone reopened an issue on GH about it, and that prompted the testfx team to open the devcomm issue for it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/151608/ability-to-set-runsettings-in-project-file.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this post [runsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2015), in case of unit testing you can set in the menu:
Test/test settings/Select Test Settings file

Comment: Thats the point, that setting is forgotten by visual studio.